# hacer un insert into y luego un update en php

Tags: php

quiero hacer un insert de un solo campo que es observaciones y luego un update a todos los demás pero me sale un error

> parse error: syntax error, unexpected 'or' (T_LOGICAL_OR)

no se si el orden en las consultas afecte.

```
<?php
include('conexion.php');
$factura=$_POST['factura'];
$hsalida=$_POST['horasa'];
$hraentrega=$_POST['horaen'];
$hllegada=$_POST['horalle'];
$chofer=$_POST['chofer'];
$vehiculo=$_POST['vehiculo'];
$direccion=$_POST['direccion'];
$fecha_entrega=$_POST['fechaent'];
$observaciones=$_POST['obser'];

$insertar=mysql_query("insert into facturacion(observaciones)values('$observaciones)");or die(mysql_error());

$query=mysql_query("update facturacion set hrasalida='$hsalida', hraentrega='$hraentrega', hrallegada='$hllegada', chofer='$chofer', vehiculo='$vehiculo', direccion='$direccion', fechaentrega='$fecha_entrega' where factura='$factura'");
if($query)
{
    ?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("Registro almacenado!");
    </script>
 <?php
}
else
{
?>
?>
    <script language="javascript">
    alert("Registro almacenado!");
    </script>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: `$insertar=mysql_query("insert into facturacion(observaciones)values('$observaciones)");or` va sin punto y coma antes del or

Comment: El mensaje de error es claro. El problema es esto: `or die(mysql_error()`, que como lo tienes ahora se interpreta como parte de la consulta de inserción. Si la función query devuelve FALSE cuando hay error entonces puedes poner el `die` cuando el resultado de dicha función sea FALSE. Algo así: `if ($insertar="...") {//código que sigue en insert exitoso }else{//aquí el mensaje de error con die o sin él... De hecho die no es usado ya por muchos programadores }` Otra cosa: la extensión `mysql_*` es obsoleta, considera migrar a PDO o a mysqli.

Comment: El ";" antes de "or die error" tienes que quitarlo, es el error que te está botando

Answer (score 1):

Como el mensaje te lo indica el error esta en esta línea

```
$insertar=mysql_query("insert into 
facturacion(observaciones)values('$observaciones')");or 
die(mysql_error());
```

Debería ser así

```
$insertar=mysql_query("insert into 
facturacion(observaciones)values('$observaciones')") 
or die(mysql_error());
```

El detalle malo es el punto y coma

Aquí la documentación para que te familiarices con la sintáxis

http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-error.php

Comment: ya corregi el punto y coma pero ahora sale esto

Comment: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near ''prueba)' at line 1

Comment: No veo dónde uses prueba

Comment: es el dato que meti en la etiqueta <textarea name="obser" id="obser"></textarea> en el formulario que tengo

Comment: @jasiel  También falta una comilla en el values `values('$observaciones)"` debería ser `values('$observaciones')"` indicar también que el código que estas escribiendo es vulnerable a inyección sql, lo recomendable seria utilizar sentencias preparadas. Un saludo.